# Test connection between two servers

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

is there way how can I from my personal computer try connection between two servers?

Me from PC want to try connection `Server1 -> Server2`

Comment: can you connect to any of those server ? what type of connexion do you want to test ? network ? ssh ? HTTP ?

Comment: Unfotunately in documentation I miss the information of protocol. There is some random port which is not standard for any protocol or connection type  I cant connect to any of theese servery, thats why I am tryint to solve it this way.

Comment: So... how can you test if the connection works if you don't know which port the connection uses?

Comment: If you can't connect to any of your host how could you test that.

Comment: Thats what I am asking, if there is possible way. Just was interested if is here some guru which can advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ping(1) (uses ICMP ECHO REQUEST/REPLY). If you suspect some sort of firewall might interfere, traceroute(8) will show the path followed to the destination (tcptraceroute(8) is a handy wrapper here). You can specify what protocol and port to use, and a slew of exotic options.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `bing` for this:

```
bing host1 host2
```

From the manpage:

> Bing determines bandwidth on a point-to-point link by sending ICMP ECHO_REQUEST packets and measuring their roundtrip times for different packet sizes on each end of the link.
>
> host1 is supposed to be the nearest end of the link, while host2 is the other end.

Comment: Unfrotunately I cant connect to any of theese servery, thats why I am tryint to solve it this way.

Comment: The user has not explained what type of connection they want to make. A ping request may succeed, but SSH may still be impossible for various reasons.

Comment: Unfotunately in documentation I miss the information of protocol. There is some random port which is not standard for any protocol or connection type